# Adding aTabPanel dynamically and making its ContentTemplate from ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webusercontrol

Context:

An AJAX Control Toolkit `TabContainer`, where each `TabPanel` is generated with code behind, and its ContentTemplate is a custom control.

The custom control corresponds to what goes directly in the `TabPanel`'s `ContentTemplate`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TabContentTemplateTest.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebGUI.Controls.TabContentTemplateTest" %>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="TabText" />
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class TabContentTemplateTest : UserControl, ITemplate
{
    public string Number { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabText.Text = Number;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        container.Controls.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Creation (code behind of `TabContainerTest`, having a `TabContainer` named `SamplesTabContainer`):

```
public string[] Numbers = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four" };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var tabContent = LoadControl("~/Controls/TabContentTemplateTest.ascx") as TabContentTemplateTest;
        tabContent.Number = Numbers[i];
        SamplesTabContainer.Tabs.Add(new TabPanel
        {
            HeaderText = i.ToString(),
            ContentTemplate = tabContent
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the content (here simplified to a label) doesn't show.

**How can I generate the custom control from ASPX as a `ContentTemplate` and display it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `TabPanel`'s `OnDemandMode` to `OnDemandMode.None` forces the addition of the controls right away, which makes them display.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `asp:ScriptManager` control, try using the `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` control instead.

I put together a test project and when using the `asp:ScriptManager` the `TabPanel` wouldn't display, though they were in the source html.  I was also getting a javascript error, 'Sys.Extended is undefined', which led to numerous web search results spanning multiple versions of the ajax toolkit.  A common suggestion was to switch script managers.  Doing so fixed the visibility of the `TabPanel` and eliminated the javascript error as well.

Specifics of test project:
VS2010
ASP.Net web app using .Net 4
IIS Express
Installed AjaxControlToolkit version 4.1.7.725 using Nuget
TabContentTemplateTest.ascx identical to code and markup in original question
Default.aspx codebehind identical to code in original question
Default.aspx markup as follows

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
         CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebGUI.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ajaxScriptManager" />
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
                              ID="SamplesTabContainer">
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The tabs already appeared in my version with `asp:ScriptManager`, but not the contents. Switching to `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` changes nothing on my end.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something crucial in my test project. Could I compare with yours?

Comment: That's really surprising. It's near identical to mine, name package version obtained with NuGet. With my answer and a simple `asp:ScriptManager` I get it to work though...

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty for your help. I was not able to reproduce your success, so I must have missed something. I think my approach is workable in most cases though, so I'm going to mark that one.

Answer (score 0):

I just see two issue with the code you shared:

- I didn't see you calling InstantiateIn() function after adding the tab.
- I would suggest using InstantiateIn(ref Control container)

Hope this helps.

Comment: `ITemplate` requires I implement `InstantiateIn(Control container)`, no `ref`.
As for calling it, That's already handled by `TabPanel.OnInit`, no?

Comment: ah! I missed that ITemplate is being implemented. The code written is self sufficient to achieve the desired functionality without even implementing Itemplate. Only you will have to call InstantiateIn() function in your code. Passing the control by reference is optional.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. `ContentTemplate` is an `ITemplate`, so it needs an `ITemplate`.